# How can I loop this animation forever?

Tags: javascript, css

Good day to everyone. I am learning javascript. I know these codes I have written are not the best of codes. I am more interested in getting my codes to work at this stage. So, I have three images I setup in HTML and styled with css.

I simply want the images to move to certain positions 3 seconds after page load and slide back to their initial positions 3 seconds interval. The problem now is that I will like to make this repeat every 3 seconds as long as the user is on the page. Here is what I have written:

Currently, the images actually slide how I want them to but I don't know how to make this happen over and over again.

```js
var section5slidersa = document.getElementById("section5slidersa");
var section5slidersb = document.getElementById("section5slidersb");
var section5slidersc = document.getElementById("section5slidersc");
var interval = 2000;



setInterval(() => {
  section5slidersa.style.left = " -500px";
  section5slidersb.style.left = "-500px";
  section5slidersc.style.left = "540px";

  setInterval(() => {
    section5slidersc.style.left = "1190px";
    section5slidersb.style.left = "0px";
    section5slidersa.style.left = " 0px";
  }, interval);


}, interval);
```

```css
 .section5container{
position: absolute;
width: 80vw;
height: 100vh;
overflow: hidden;   
}

.section5slides{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 500px 500px 500px;
gap: 20px;
position: absolute;
left: 210px;
top: 170px;    
}

 

.section5sliders{
background: #111924;
height: 220px;
}

   

.section5sliders img{
width: 200px;
height: 180px;
position: relative;
top: 5px;   
}

.imgbg{
background: #98ACB5;
width: 190px;
height: 180px;
position: relative;
top: 20px;
left: 20px;
}





#section5slidersa {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  transition: .8s ease-out;
}

#section5slidersb {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  transition: .8s ease-out;
}

#section5slidersc {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  left: 1190px;
  transition: .8s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="section5container">
<div class="section5slides">
<div class="section5sliders" id="section5slidersa"
<div class="imgbg"><img src="https://www.freeimages.com/photo/hand-in-
action-aiming-1-1431523" id="section5imga" alt=""></div>
</div>


<div class="section5sliders" id="section5slidersb">
<div class="imgbg"><img src="https://www.freeimages.com/photo/frog-on-
chain-link-fence-1560508" id="section5imgb" alt=""></div>
</div>

   

  <div class="section5sliders" id="section5slidersc">
<div class="imgbg"><img src="https://www.freeimages.com/photo/chain-
1446690" id="section5imgc" alt=""></div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet I made you with relevant HTML. You can get images from lorem kitten or placeholder.com

Comment: Could you create a codepen (https://codepen.io/pen/) or JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first split the slides into two functions, slideLeft and slideRight.

In slideLeft, we want to call slideRight after `interval` ms after it finishes. In slideRight, we want to call slideLeft after `interval` ms after it finishes. We can solve this by adding `setTimeout(otherFunction, interval)` to the bottom of each function.

Finally, we can call `slideLeft()` to begin the animation

```js
var section5slidersa = document.getElementById("section5slidersa");
var section5slidersb = document.getElementById("section5slidersb");
var section5slidersc = document.getElementById("section5slidersc");
var interval = 2000;

slideLeft();
function slideLeft() {
  section5slidersa.style.left = " -500px";
  section5slidersb.style.left = "-500px";
  section5slidersc.style.left = "540px";
  setTimeout(slideRight, interval);
}

function slideRight() {
  section5slidersc.style.left = "1190px";
  section5slidersb.style.left = "0px";
  section5slidersa.style.left = " 0px";
  setTimeout(slideLeft, interval);
}
```

```css
#section5slidersa {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  transition: .8s ease-out;
}

#section5slidersb {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  transition: .8s ease-out;
}

#section5slidersc {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  left: 1190px;
  transition: .8s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <body>
   <img id="section5slidersa" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
   <img id="section5slidersb" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
   <img id="section5slidersc" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much. You have solved my problem that has taken me 3 nights. This worked perfectly as I wanted. I will simply adjust how the animation starts. Thank you so much. I am super excited and most importantly, I learnt something new from your code.

Comment: Hi jdabtieu if you wouldn't mind, is it possible to set a clearTimeOut on this codes you wrote? I was thinking I could do it by setting clearTimeOut on mouseover and remove the 'interval'. Maybe I am not doing it rightly.

Comment: @Kingsley should be possible, with a modification like the one described here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

Comment: Thanks, man. The link you provided really helped me. I have been able to pause the slider on mouse enter and mouse leave using event listener. I can also control the slides using the two buttons and the slides resume appropriately. Thank you so much for the link. Learnt a lot too.